# Google Map Places Api Error: STATUS CODE 9011 | Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

I am trying to use places api in android app. But I got error status code 9011. As per the documentation (https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/reference/com/google/android/libraries/places/api/net/PlacesStatusCodes) this error code means **Operation failed due to authorization issues**. Billing is enabled on account and maps and places API is enabled. Maps API is working on the app.

Here is the code:

```
if (!Places.isInitialized())
             Places.initialize(getApplicationContext(),getResources().getString(R.string.map_api_key));
 AutocompleteSessionToken token = AutocompleteSessionToken.newInstance();
        // Create a RectangularBounds object.

        // Use the builder to create a FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest.
        FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest request = FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest.builder()
                // Call either setLocationBias() OR setLocationRestriction().
                //.setLocationRestriction(bounds)
                .setCountry("ng")//Nigeria
                .setTypeFilter(TypeFilter.ADDRESS)
                .setSessionToken(token)
                .setQuery("SaltLak")
                .build();


        placesClient.findAutocompletePredictions(request).addOnSuccessListener(response -> {
          StringBuilder  mResult = new StringBuilder();
            for (AutocompletePrediction prediction : response.getAutocompletePredictions()) {
                mResult.append(" ").append(prediction.getFullText(null) + "\n");
                Log.i(TAG, prediction.getPlaceId());
                Log.i(TAG, prediction.getPrimaryText(null).toString());
            }
            Log.i(TAG, mResult.toString());
        }).addOnFailureListener((exception) -> {
            if (exception instanceof ApiException) {
                ApiException apiException = (ApiException) exception;
                Log.e(TAG, "Place not found: " + apiException.getStatusCode());
            }
        });
```

Comment: Did you properly create `Places` client `PlacesClient placesClient = Places.createClient(getApplicationContext());` ?

Comment: yes..i have paced

Comment: Based on the documentation the error is related to your API key. May I know how are you specifying your API key on your app? Does your API key have restrictions? If so, try to remove the restriction first and see if it works.

Comment: no restriction.

Comment: Alright. May I know how you are specifying the key on your app?

Comment: <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/map_api_key" />
in manifest file

Comment: Are you putting in your key directly in the manifest file like this? `<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="AIza...xxxx" /> ` or are you defining it somewhere else?

Comment: in string xml i have put it..